# How to compare lists of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

I have a super array of ones which is 1x1000.

```
su = np.ones(1000)
```

And 3 lists, of indices between (1,1000).

```
l1=random.sample(range(1, 1000), 320)
l2=random.sample(range(1, 1000), 340)
l3=random.sample(range(1, 1000), 412)
```

Basically these lists represent the indices w.r.t super-array at which their values are one.

How can I compare these three lists without even inflating them or interpolating them on the super-array.

A small example --->

Consider these two arrays `a1=[0,1,1,0,0];a2= [1,1,0,0,0]` They both can be represented as `a1_=[1,2]; a2_=[0,1]` for the indices their value=1. Now its easy to compare the representation of a1,a1 as

```
In [593]:cosine_distances(a1,a2)
Out[594]: array([[ 0.5]])
```

but how would you compare if given in form of `a1_, a2_` . Thats what Im asking precisely

Comment: What sort of comparison do you want to perform?

Comment: cosine distance `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity`

Comment: Mention this in the question

Comment: What do you mean by comparing the lists? Can you incorporate a few examples into your question, by giving sample lists and the result of their comparison?

Comment: @vinita added an answer specific to `cosine_similarity`

Comment: Is there a name for such compressed representation of a sparse array, wherein you just save the indices where an array has a value of 1 ?

Comment: This `sklearn` calculator accepts `scipy.sparse` matrices.  I've added that to my answer.

Comment: @vinita, do any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are looking for common elements in l1, l2, l3? You could use sets for that:

```
s1 = set(l1)
s2 = set(l2)
s3 = set(l3)
```

Then find common / different indices using `s1.intersection(s2)` and `s1.difference(s2)` respectively. A simple length check:

```
assert len(s1) == len(s1.intersection(s2)) + len(s1.difference(s2))
```

There is no output, hence lengths add up correctly as expected.

Comment: Consider these two arrays `a1=[0,1,1,0,0];a2= [1,1,0,0,0]` They both can be represented as `a1_=[1,2]; a2_=[0,1]` for the indices their value=1. Now its easy to compare the representation of `a1,a1` but how would you compare if given in form of `a1_, a2_` . Thats what Im asking precisely

Answer (score 0):

It should be easily possible to compare the cosine similarity between these two vectors. For a cosine similarity, you need the modulus of each vector along with the dot product of the two vectors.

Since the vector just consists of ones and zeros, the modulus is easy, the number of 1s in the vector, square rooted.

```
l1_mod = math.sqrt(len(l1))
l2_mod = math.sqrt(len(l2))
```

Now the dot product is trickier, you need to find out the number of common elements between the two vectors. You should use [`np.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html), since you are dealing with one dimensional arrays.

```
dot = len(np.intersect1d(l1, l2))
simililarity = dot / (l1_mod*l2_mod)
```

Needless to say, wrap this up into a single function!

Answer (score 0):

### Dense array solution

It's easy to convert the `a_` form to the `a` one, with a function like:

```
def foo(a_, n):
    a = np.zeros(n,int)
    a[a_] = 1
    return a

In [1565]: foo([1,2],5)
Out[1565]: array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
In [1566]: foo([0,1],5)
Out[1566]: array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Using the simple lists, the function gives the desired value, but with a warning.

```
In [1572]: a1=[0,1,1,0,0];a2= [1,1,0,0,0]
In [1573]: pairwise.cosine_distances(a1,a2)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
Out[1573]: array([[ 0.5]])
```

So I need to modify my `foo` so it too creates the (1,5) arrays:

```
def foo(a_, n):
   a = np.zeros((1,n),int)
   a[:,a_] = 1
   return a

In [1575]: pairwise.cosine_distances(foo([1,2],5),foo([0,1],5))
Out[1575]: array([[ 0.5]])
```

### sparse matrix solution

`cosine_distance` accepts sparse matrix inputs.

The easiest way to make a sparse matrix is to just use a dense array, or even the `a1` list

```
In [1580]: from scipy import sparse
In [1592]: sparse.csr_matrix(a1)
Out[1592]: 
<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [1593]: sparse.csr_matrix(a1).A    # view it as a dense array
Out[1593]: array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [1594]: pairwise.cosine_distances( sparse.csr_matrix(a1), sparse.csr_matrix(a2))
Out[1594]: array([[ 0.5]])
```

So as an intermediate step I can do:

```
In [1581]: sparse.csr_matrix(foo([1,2],5))
Out[1581]: 
<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The next step is to make the sparse matrix directly from the `a_` format.  That requires a bit more knowledge about sparse matrices.

Using the sparse `coo` style of input:

```
In [1601]: sparse.csr_matrix(([1,1],([0,0],[1,2])), shape=(1,5)).A
Out[1601]: array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)

def mkcsr(a_, n):
    col = np.array(a_)
    row = np.zeros_like(col)
    data = np.ones_like(col)
    return sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(1,n))

In [1611]: mkcsr([1,2],5).A
Out[1611]: array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [1614]: pairwise.cosine_distances(mkcsr([1,2],5), mkcsr([0,1],5))
Out[1614]: array([[ 0.5]])
```

Comment: The OP does not want to convert the arrays into their true form

Comment: I've added a sparse matrix solution.